# Messages not being sent over WebSocket server (asyncio, websockets libraries)

Tags: python, tkinter, websocket, async-await, arduino

```
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio
import threading
import websockets
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

async def connect_to_websocket_server():
            return await websockets.connect('ws://192.168.236.189:8765')
        
async def send_command(websocket, command):
        
        await websocket.send(command)
async def receive_response(websocket):
        return await websocket.recv()


class FingerApp():

    


    def __init__(self, websocket):
        # print(f"This part1 is running")
        # Define the serial port and baud rate. Adjust these values according to your Arduino settings.
        # self.ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 115200, timeout=1)
        self.websocket = websocket
        # Map finger names to corresponding commands
        self.finger_commands = {
            "Thumb": "0\n",
            "Index": "1\n",
            "Middle": "2\n",
            "Ring": "3\n",
            "Pinky": "4\n",
        }



        # Start the GUI in a separate thread
        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.create_hand_gui())

        # gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.create_hand_gui())
        gui_thread.start()

    async def display_info(self, finger, info_label):
        logging.debug(f"This part2 is running")
        
        command = self.finger_commands.get(finger)
        print(command)
        if command:
                try:
                    # Send the command to the serial port
                    # self.ser.write(command.encode('utf-8'))
                    # await websocket.send(command)
                    # websocket = await self.connect_to_websocket_server()
                    # async with websockets.connect('ws://192.168.236.189:8765') as websocket:
                        # await self.send_command(websocket, command)
                    await self.websocket.send(command)  # Send command to Websocket server
                    logging.debug(f"Sent command: {command}")
                    # output = await websocket.recv()  # Wait for the response from the serial port
                        # output = await self.receive_response(websocket)  # Wait for the response from the Websocket server
                    output = await self.websocket.recv()  # Wait for the response from the Websocket server
                    logging.debug(f"Received response: {output}")
                    # Read and update the label with the response from the serial port
                    if output:
                        response = output.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
                        info_label.config(text="The angle calculated is " + response + " degrees", fg='green')
                    else:
                        info_label.config(text="No response from the serial port", fg='red')

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Error: {e}")
        else:
            info_label.config(text="Invalid finger", fg='orange')

    def create_finger_button(self, canvas, x, y, finger, info_label):
        # print(f"This part3 is running")
        # Create oval button
        button = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + 50, y + 30, fill="white", outline="black")

        # Bind enter event to start continuous display on hover
        canvas.tag_bind(button, '<Enter>', lambda event: self.start_continuous_display(finger, info_label, canvas, button))

        # Bind leave event to stop continuous display when not hovered
        canvas.tag_bind(button, '<Leave>', lambda event: self.stop_continuous_display(info_label, canvas, button))

        return button

    def start_continuous_display(self, finger, info_label, canvas, button):
        # print(f"This part4 is running")
        # Start a continuous display of information while hovering
        canvas.itemconfig(button, fill='gray')
        self.display_info_continuously(finger, info_label)

    def display_info_continuously(self, finger, info_label):
        # Continuously update information while hovering
        # print(f"This part5 is running")
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.display_info(finger, info_label))
        self.continuous_display_id = info_label.after(100, lambda: self.display_info_continuously(finger, info_label))

    def stop_continuous_display(self, info_label, canvas, button):
        # print(f"This part6 is running")
        # Stop continuous display when not hovered
        canvas.itemconfig(button, fill='white')
        info_label.config(text="", fg='black')
        info_label.after_cancel(self.continuous_display_id)

    def create_hand_gui(self):
        # print(f"This part7 is running")
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Finger Information App")

        # Create a label to display information
        info_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold"), bg="white", relief="solid", width=40, height=2)

        info_label.pack()

        # Load the background image
        bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\sudhi\Desktop\codes\2Basics\hand.png")


        # Create a canvas with the background image
        canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=bg_image.width(), height=bg_image.height(), bg='white')
        canvas.pack()

        canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=bg_image)

        # Create oval buttons on the hand with hover effect
        self.create_finger_button(canvas, 150, 390, "Thumb", info_label)
        self.create_finger_button(canvas, 288, 140, "Index", info_label)
        self.create_finger_button(canvas, 420, 75, "Middle", info_label)
        self.create_finger_button(canvas, 547, 125, "Ring", info_label)
        self.create_finger_button(canvas, 637, 252, "Pinky", info_label)

        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.to_thread(root.destroy())))
        
        root.mainloop()

    # async def on_close(self,websocket):
    #     # Ensure the serial port is closed when the GUI is closed
    #     await websocket.close()


async def main():
    # print(f"This part8 is running")
    websocket = await connect_to_websocket_server()
    app = FingerApp(websocket)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
     asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
     loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I tried creating a GUI for my hand glove that measures PIP angle of each finger.
The python code above acts as a client that gets the angle data from the WebSockets server.
When pointing a cursor over a finger, the GUI has to send a command to the WebServer, which in return sends the corresponding angle to the GUI.

I don't know why but the angle is not being displayed on the screen. Then I tried debugging and when closing the GUI, found these messages appearing in terminal

```
File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 689, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
DEBUG:root:This part2 is running
4

DEBUG:websockets.client:> TEXT '4\n' [2 bytes]
DEBUG:root:Sent command: 4

DEBUG:root:This part2 is running
4

DEBUG:websockets.client:> TEXT '4\n' [2 bytes]
DEBUG:root:Sent command: 4

ERROR:root:Error: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message
DEBUG:root:This part2 is running
4

DEBUG:websockets.client:> TEXT '4\n' [2 bytes]
DEBUG:root:Sent command: 4

ERROR:root:Error: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message
DEBUG:root:This part2 is running
```

I'm an intermediate skilled person, could anyone help me in achieving this?